# Is it possible to build a Mac binary on a non-Mac unix machine?

Tags: c++, macos

I would like to set up a Mac buildbot slave, but unfortunately it's not possible to install Mac OS X 10.5 on my XenServer hypervisor. So, I've had an idea, but not quite sure whether or not it'll work. The application is C++, and on Mac it's compile using GNU Make. I have a Mac desktop PC, and I was hoping I could copy the .h and .lib files on to a Linux box, and try to build against the Mac headers:

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <AvailabilityMacros.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cross compile.  gcc can create many versions of object files, not dependent upon what sort of host system you are running.  mac uses a VERY old version of the gcc suite that they have forked for OSX development so even though it's possible, it's not going to be easy.

Essentially, search for cross compiling on the gcc compiler, but be sure that it will take a substantial effort to do this.

[edit]

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows) for an answer (albeit a different host machine OS)

[/edit]