# Qt cross compilation

Tags: windows, qt, cross-compiling

I want Qt software to be cross compiled for powerpc architecture on windows machine.on,linux machine i am able to do this task by giving the exact qmake specification for xplatform option. but i am not able to this from windows machine.

i had powerpc tool chain installed on my windows machine.

please tell me in detail how i can cross compile Qt software for powerpc architecture from windows machine. its very urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of a duplicate question, see [How to Compile for OS X in Linux or Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows).

For what it's worth, cross-compiling is usually not worth the hassle; in almost all cases, your best bet is a setup using a virtual machine, since you need a way to test the resulting binaries anyways.