# Compiling for Mac/Linux on Windows

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, build-process, cross-platform, cross-compiling

Obviously you can't really run Mac or Linux apps on Windows, but can you compile binaries for those platforms using MSVC++ for example (plugging in additional compilers and tools obviously)? For a serious build system, you don't want one build server per platform so having an automated build server which compiles for all target platforms seems quite a reasonable aim.

Comment: A build server hosting a number of VMs is quite a standard approach now.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't thought of it. But you can't virtualize Macs (legally), can you?

Comment: AFAIK the only legal way to virtualize a Mac is to host the virtual Mac on a real Mac.  So if you don't mind having a Mac (with gobs of RAM) as your build server, you can get an all-in-one-machine build process that way.

Comment: @John: how I understand Apple's terms: you are allowed to virtualize Mac OS on Mac hardwware, ie if the VM runs on Mac hardware (read: over-priced white plain hardware), you are allowed to run Mac OS in the VM. Does it help you? Probably not, because you'd still need a Mac, and why vitualize what you've then lready got `;)`

Comment: Suppose you can run a Mac and then virtualize Windows/Linux on it, but I don't consider Mac Server to be sensible, aren't they phasing it out?

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crosstool-NG](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool) seems like your best option for Linux apps; they show that as one of the standard configurations.  I do not know about Mac OS X; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows) suggests that it will probably be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to believe (notice my careful words) that GCC can be built to run on windows (any relevant form of the triplet *-*-mingw*) and target another triplet.

A proof-of-concept for the non-believers is provided [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20NonWin/vityan/), where you can find Win64 hosted compilers that build native linux binaries. I assume the same can be done for mac if the necessary libraries (like the CRT and necessary Mac framework libraries) can be built/used by that compiler.

Comment: I'd like to believe it too... as I say originally, technically it should be _possible_...

Answer (score -3):

if you want to build applications using `C++`, why not use `Qt` from Nokia. it's cross platform. http://qt.nokia.com/

Comment: Qt is an application framework, ie a library with associated tools and code style and preferred classes. Qt or not is irrelevant here, more so because Qt disallows/disencourages cross-compilation.