# How to compile executable for Mac, but from a PC?

Tags: python, compilation

I need to compile my application for both PC and Mac, but I don't have access to Mac in my area (very rare, mostly PC). My application written in Python with 2 C++ modules, I used pyInstaller for Python and MinGW for C++ in PC, but question is for Mac?

What can I do? is there any OS emulator or something helpful out there?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "cross compiling"

Comment: What he's looking for is words.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate Apple OS and any other OS on VMWare.

Comment: Last time I checked, you couldn't do that without already having apple hardware (or going through a very painful process to get around that "feature").

Comment: The current VirtualBox runs OSX just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm), there are a few tools for cross compiling python. I particularly like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).