# Export native Mac executable from GCC C compiler?

Tags: c, windows, macos, gcc, compiler-construction

What argument do I need to use to export an executable file that will run on Mac from my Windows machine?

```
gcc *.c -o Program.? -?
```

*? = what goes here?

Comment: Define: "run on Mac from my Windows machine" Are you trying to cross-compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows)

Comment: You cannot do that directly, you need a cross-compiler setup. And it is far from being obvious to set up :/

Comment: The Apple gcc (or clang/llvm) will not produce any Windows executables at all, if you want to do that. As written my Mystical, you need a cross-compiler or compile the project on Windows/Linux/whatever.

Comment: What I mean is how can I compile a Apple/Linux executable from the GCC compiler installed on my Windows machine?

Comment: I'm getting the impression that it isn't possible... hmm.  Well back to Java!