# How to package a parser generated with Antlr

Tags: c++, antlr, software-distribution

I'm a student. I have made a small language for computer-architectural simulations as a part of my project. I have made a parser+translator for this language using Antlr3. Stuff written in my language gets translated to C++ code, which can be compiled and executed by the user to run the simulation.

I don't have any experience in packaging software (that is, making it suitable for others to install and use easily). Although currently I'm the only one using it, I would like to know **what is a good way to package it**, so I can share it with others.

I want to package:

- antlr generated Lexer+Parser for my language
- code that wraps around the antlr-generated stuff
- the antlr C runtime library.

How can I distribute all this as a translator for my language?

I remember that when I installed the C runtime library, stuff that was specific to my machine/OS was taken care of. (For example, how end-of-file is represented). Should I assume users of my translator have installed the C runtime separately?

Thanks,

-neha

Comment: Compiling for different platforms can be a pain, but it can be done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows for an idea of the work involved.

Answer (score 0):

You want to package it for.... what?

- RPM (e.g. CentOS) read here: http://www.gurulabs.com/downloads/GURULABS-RPM-LAB/GURULABS-RPM-GUIDE-v1.0.PDF
- For Debian: http://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian
- On OsX, package via homebrew: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Formula-Cookbook