# How to produce a .app file using Qt creator in windows?

Tags: windows, macos, qt-creator, qt5

I have recently installed the Qt creator in Windows, I can build project and use the exe in windows. I want to build for OS X snow Leopard.

What kits or build configurations should I use. I have explored all the options and searched the net but can't find an answer 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Compile for OS X in Linux or Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows)

searched 'compile for other os' and got it as second result ...

Comment: Dear Zaiborg, thankyou for helping. however, I am concerned specifically about Qt creator and its kits and configurations...

Comment: why? i compile at work with the vs2008 shipped compiler and use the clang64 for mac at home. under linux i use the default gcc (i think) and there is no problem compiling on each platform if the code has no os specific code in it (like #include "windows.h")