# cross compiling for macosx

Tags: c, macos, command-line, cross-compiling

I have an occasional requirement to port simple, *command-line only C programs* developed and tested on Linux, to MacOSX. All I was able to find in how-to's on the subject floating around the 'net was quite complicated, and requited apple software/hardware (which I do not have and have no time or budget to acquire). One of the reasons for this seems to be that most of those how-to's assumed compiling and building of GUI programs - something that I have no need for.

What would be the simplest method of achieving this?

Comment: Semi-related, how are you planning to test that the software you ported actually works on the target system if you don't have access to it?

Comment: Please check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows could be a starting point

Comment: Although, frankly, @UnholySheep has a point and ssh-ing to a Mac OS X host with a configured GCC toolchain would be one of the most reliable options

Comment: Rent a Mac in the cloud https://www.macincloud.com and `ssh` into it and use Apple's `clang` compiler. Note that this is not an endorsement - I have never used the services of this company, I am merely aware that they, and others, exist.

Comment: @UnholySheep: These are mathematical simulation/analysis  programs: they read a text file, do (a lot of) calculations and print text on the console (that can be redirected to another text file). All required testing is accomplished on the primary development computer (Linux); if OSX compilation executes, it "is correct". (Example input files with expected results are published). "Distribution" is done by posting binaries on the website.