# How to make an SDL2 c++ executable for Mac while working on Windows?

Tags: c++, exe, sdl-2

Made a small SDL2 application, compiled it. Tried sharing with user on macOS, along with SDL2.dll. But he could not open it, and it said: "You can't open the application because Microsoft Windows applications are not supported on macOS". Is there another way to compile? Or maybe there are some platform specific commands for which I should watch out.

Comment: Search term: "Cross Compiler".

Comment: Related but old: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows)

Comment: Tell 'em to run it using [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)), it should work without any problems. What you ask for is rarely done, so it's not going to be easy.